I can't boot into debian after running apt upgrade. UUID=xxx does not exist. Dropping to shell!
I was trying to install virtualbox, following the instructions on the Debian wiki and added this line to /etc/apt/sources.list:
# Debian Unstable "Sid"
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ sid main contrib non-free

And I think this is where the mistake was made on my part because I didn't really read what I was doing, but after running apt update and apt upgrade, when I rebooted my machine, I got past the grub screen and when I selected to boot into Debian it hung for a minute and gave me this error:

I've tried booting into recovery mode but that gave me the same error. I have read posts by people with similar errors who were told to go into the BIOS and change some setting to AHCI, but my BIOS doesn't even have that option. I have a live USB that I can use to troubleshoot, and maybe fix it but I'm not exactly sure how to go about that. Help would be appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks.

You added the entirety of the unstable version of Debian to your repository list. Unless you like chancing your system this is generally a very bad idea. Testing, sure, but Unstable (Sid)?? The instructions also explained how to install VBox without relying on Sid

Have you tried to use the shell to investigate a bit, at least look at what block devices are available?

For me, this was caused by this bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1079031
The bug results in the initrd image for the latest kernel being almost empty, lacking the functionality to boot from your drive.
Booting a previous kernel/initrd using the Grub menu "Advanced options ..." and picking a previous version (I used 6.9.11) allowed me to get the system running. After that, simply updating my system produced a valid initrd image as the bug has been fixed already.

Unfortunately, I was not able to get the system running by picking a previous kernel version.
